# Rails Book Suggestions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a canonical book on Ruby on Rails?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27410/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-ruby-on-rails)

I'm looking to learn Ruby on Rails. I already have a small background in Ruby and don't really need a book that covers both, as I ordered the Pickaxe Book a couple days ago. I recently read some of Beginning Ruby on Rails-Steven Holzner, but abandoned that after seeing multiple statements on SO about how terrible the code in it was, and also the fact that it used Rails 1...Just wondering, what is the best book for an ABSOLUTE BEGINNER in Rails?

Comment: Flagged for merging with duplicate.